# CampaignMember triggers not executed on a Lead deletion

Tags: apex, trigger

I was recently trying out some functionalities and it happened to me that the delete trigger on CampaignMembers did not fire when I deleted a Lead (which has a campaign Member, of course).

I checked with the metadata definition, and Campaign Members should be deleted on cascade:

```
CampaignMember.LeadId  
    cascadeDelete: true
    childSObject: CampaignMember
    deprecatedAndHidden: false
    field: LeadId
    relationshipName: CampaignMembers
```

I checked the events of my trigger:

```
trigger CampaignMemberTrigger on CampaignMember (before insert, before update, before delete, after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) { ... }
```

Then I double checked with the following code.

First I prepared the environment:

```
Lead l = new Lead(Email = 'test@test.test', LastName = 'MyName', Company = 'MyCompany');
insert l;

Campaign c = new Campaign(Name = 'Some Campaign');
insert c;

insert new CampaignMember(LeadId = l.Id, CampaignId = c.Id);
```

Afterwards I executed my test:

```
delete [SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE LastName = 'MyName'];
```

And lastly I checked the debug log (filtered by *CODE_UNIT_STARTED*):

[image]

So, at the end of the day... what's happening here? I'm a bit lost. **On the creation of the Campaign Member the trigger was fired, but when I delete the lead, it isn't.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per Salesforce docs: [Operations That Don't Invoke Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_ignoring_operations.htm)

> Cascading delete operations. Records that did not initiate a delete
>   don't cause trigger evaluation.

So you are seeing an expected behavior here. A Cascading delete will not fire CampaignMember Trigger.

Comment: very nice @Tushar